# Vector disperso operaciones

Tags: c++

estoy haciendo esta clase llamada matriz, y quiero trabajar con arrays dinámicos, istreams ostreams, con vectores dispersos, pero no he sido capaz de arrancar, esto es lo que hice, se agradece cualquier idea:

```
// Operaciones con matrices:suma,resta,multiplicación, inversa istream ostream

#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class matriz {
private:
    const int m_ = 50; //filas primera matriz
    const int n_ = 50:

    const int f_ = 50; //filas segunda matriz
    const int c_ = 50;

    const int b_ = 50;//filas matriz suma
    const int e_ = 50;

    int A[m_][n_];
    int B[f_][c_];

    int C[b_][e_];

    double * val_;
    int*  inx_;
    int  nz_;
    int n_;

    int *M= new int [m_*n_]; // array dinamico primera matriz
    int *N= new int [f_*c_]; // array dinamico segunda matriz

public:

    //constructores
    matriz (const int m,const int n, const int f, const int c) {
        m_=m;
        n_=n;
        f_=f;
        c_=c;
    }

    ~matriz() {}
    //getters y setters
    void setm_ (const int m) {m_=m;}

    const int getm_(void) {return m_;}

    void setn_ (const int n) {n_=n}

    const int getn_(void) {return n_;}

    void setf_ (const int n) {n_=n;}
    const int getf_(void) {return f_;}

    void setc_(const int c) {c_=c;}
    const int getc_ (void) {return c_;}

    //métodos


    int suma(void);

    int resta(void);

    int multiplicacion(void);

    int inversa(void);
};

for (int i=0; i<
```

Hasta aquí lo que hice, se agradece ayuda muchas muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Deberías pasarte por el [tour de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber cómo funciona este portal. Esta pregunta tiene demasiados errores de forma (preguntar cómo avanzar los deberes no es una buena forma de empezar).

Comment: No es claro cuál es tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Errores o incongruencias de tu código:

1. Las líneas de código finalizan con punto y coma, no con dos puntos

   ```
   const int n_ = 50:
   //               ^
   ```
2. Las variables deben ser descriptivas para que el código sea legible. Si necesitas un comentario para saber qué funcion tiene esa variable es que estás haciendo algo mal.

   ```
   const int m_ = 50; // Que es m_? 
   const int n_ = 50; // y n_? que diferencia hay entre ambas?

   const int f_ = 50; // idem
   const int c_ = 50; // idem

   const int b_ = 50; // idem
   const int e_ = 50; // idem
   ```
3. Si quieres trabajar con dimensiones dinámicas **no puedes** declarar las variables como constantes

   ```
   const int m_ = 50; // m_ no deberia ser const

   void setm_ (const int m) {m_=m;} // Error m_ es constante
   ```
4. Si quieres dimensiones constantes tienes que usar memoria dinámica (`new` y `delete`) en vez de crear arrays basados en tamaño fijo

   ```
   int A[m_][n_]; // A siempre sera de 50x50
   int B[f_][c_]; // B siempre sera de 50x50

   int C[b_][e_]; // C siempre sera de 50x50
   ```
5. Si quieres usar varios arrays siempre será preferible crear varios objetos de tipo `matriz`.

   ```
   int A[m_][n_]; // memoria interna del objeto array
   int B[f_][c_]; // sobra
   int C[b_][e_]; // sobra
   ```
6. Las reservas dinámicas de memoria se realizan en tiempo de ejecución, no de compilación. En consecuencia, estas inicializaciones deben hacerse dentro de alguna función (como por ejemplo el constructor)

   ```
   // Incorrecto
   int *M= new int [m_*n_];
   int *N= new int [f_*c_];

   // Correcto (una posibilidad)
   matriz()
     : M(new int[m_*n_])
       N(new int[f_*c_])
   { }
   ```
7. Si para la gestión interna de un objeto haces reservas dinámicas de memoria a malas el destructor debe encargarse de liberar dichas reservas

   ```
   ~matriz()
   {
     delete[] M;
     delete[] N;
   }
   ```

¿Cómo debería quedar la clase entonces?

Al final lo sencillo suele ser lo que mejor funciona (al menos al principio):

- Cada objeto de tipo `matriz` debería gestionar únicamente una matriz de datos
- Cambiar las dimensiones de forma dinámica no va a estar permitido. Para ello es preferible crear un nuevo objeto

  - si las dimensiones son mayores, ¿cómo se inicializan las nuevas celdas?
  - si las dimensiones son menores, ¿es aceptable perder datos?
- Hace falta un mecanismo para modificar los valores de la matriz.

Una solución a la interfaz:

```
class matriz {

  int filas_;
  int columnas_;

  int *datos_;

public:

  //constructores
  matriz(int filas, int columnas)
    : filas_(filas),
      columnas_(columnas),
      datos_(new int[filas*columnas])
  {
  }

  ~matriz()
  {
    delete[] datos_;
  }


  //métodos
  int& Valores(int fila, int columna)
  {
    return datos_[fila*columnas_+columna];
  }

  matriz suma(matriz const& otra) const;
  matriz resta(matriz const& otra) const;
  matriz multiplicacion(matriz const& otra) const;
  matriz inversa(matriz const& otra) const;
};
```

Consejo final: No te metas en camisas de once varas si tus base de C++ es escasa.